# Any performance hit or overhead for wrapping public methods?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm writing a class to handle a custom content type for WordPress. WP's native custom post type + custom post meta (which resides in a table without indexes) is not an option because I need some metadata columns stored in the same table and have them indexed.

But for cleaner and simpler code in my templates I'd like to define custom template functions, which are basically wrappers for class methods. For example, there's a native function `get_post()`, I would like to have a function `my_get_event()`, the code will be smth like this:

```
function my_get_event( $args ) {
    return $event->get( $args );
}
```

What I would like to know about this approach:

1. Is there any performance hit if I have, let's say, 5 different classes and 50-60 wrapper functions in total?
2. Is there any memory footprint increase?
3. Maybe there's another way to go?

Comment: Well, you could also benchmark it and see...On top of my head, I don't think it would make it worst than how wordpress already is